# FileNotFoundException when loading assembly of ASP.NET Core MVC 5 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-assembly, .net-5

I'm trying to explore an assembly that belongs to an ASP.NET Core MVC project. The project was made with .NET 5.

The problem is, when I try to explore the assembly's types, it throws a `FileNotFoundException` with the following message: `Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado`.

Issuing a `dotnet build` command compiles the project without problems.

Exploring the corresponding .csproj file, I found that the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core` dependency is not declared in the project file, but the SDK indicated in the project file's XML root is `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`, and I understand that marks the project as an ASP.NET Core project, but I can't find a way to bring the necessary dependencies to load the assembly.

Code as follows.

Code that loads the assembly:

```cs
var reader_context = new ReaderLoadContext(artifact_dir);
var assembly_path = ""; //Path of the compiled assembly
var assembly = reader_context.LoadFromAssemblyPath(assembly_path);
//Here's where it crashes
var target_types = assembly.ExportedTypes.Where(t => t.BaseType != null && t.BaseType.Name == "ControllerBase").ToArray();
```

`ReaderLoadContext`'s code:

```cs
public class ReaderLoadContext : AssemblyLoadContext
{
    private AssemblyDependencyResolver _resolver;

    public ReaderLoadContext(string readerLocation)
    {
        _resolver = new AssemblyDependencyResolver(readerLocation);
    }

    protected override Assembly Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
    {
        var assembly_path = _resolver.ResolveAssemblyToPath(assemblyName);
        if (assembly_path != null)
        {
            return LoadFromAssemblyPath(assembly_path);
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected override IntPtr LoadUnmanagedDll(string unmanagedDllName)
    {
        var library_path = _resolver.ResolveUnmanagedDllToPath(unmanagedDllName);
        if (library_path != null)
        {
            return LoadUnmanagedDllFromPath(library_path);
        }
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to confirm with you whether you have upgraded your project? for testing purposes, in your project could you try to right click Dependencies-> Manage Nuget Packages-> Search Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core under browse tab and install the package. Rebuild your project and try to run the project to see whether it makes any difference. [See Here](https://imgur.com/a/cJzJEXm).

Comment: I added the package you suggested and compiled the project in VS, no problems. Ran the project that analyzes the solution, throws the same exception. One important detail: the latest version of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core` available in Nuget is 2.2.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out [this is a known limitation of AssemblyLoadContext](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1050#issuecomment-596451182) and one of the solutions (more like an ugly workaround) is to add a reference to the missing framework in the application that explores the desired assembly. I added a `PackageReference` item in my app's .csproj file and now it properly loads the assembly I want to scan.

I don't know if I should mark this as an answer. In one hand, it does what I need it to. OTOH, it forces the developer to add all possible framework references beforehand just in case, and if Microsoft (or a 3rd party) releases another framework, it requires releasing a new version of the app.

So hopefully someone knows a more elegant solution.

Thanks to @deepak-msft and everyone else for the help.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution to the said issue. I would suggest you mark your own answer to this question whenever it is available to mark it. It could help other community members in the future with similar issues. Thanks for your understanding.